# Starting Directory for Bash

Tags: docker, bashrc

I've a Docker container running. I connect to the container using a command like:

```
docker exec -it container_name bash
```

This logs in as root at `/var/www/html`. I want to know why this directory, and how I would go about changing it. This is actually a web application's container and I do want to start in the web applications content root, but that's on a differently named volume defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

I checked `.profile` and `.bashrc` and nothing seems to indicate that it would start in this directory and be obvious to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working directory in a container is specified with `WORKDIR` instruction in `Dockerfile`. You can also change the working by specifying `-w` parameter for `docker run` or with `working_dir` attribute in `docker-compose.yml`.